# Finding surjection from injection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I looked at many of the similar questions, and I struggled to digest them - I'm taking my first math class that involves proofs, so I think my background was a bit weak.

The question: 
             Suppose there is an injection f: A -> B. Prove there must exist a surjection g: B -> A.

My attempt:

Suppose there is an injection f: A -> B. By definition of injection,
f($a_{1}$) = f($a_{2}$) -> $a_{1}$ = $a_{2}$.

Define a function g: B -> A, g(b) = a for all b$\in$B

g $\circ$ f (a) = f(g(a)) = a for all a$\in$A. 
This works because f is an injection, so f takes every element of A to a unique element of B. 
Further, the domain of g $\circ$ f is able to each every element of its co-domain. So g $\circ$ f is a surjection -> g is a surjection. 
Q.E.D.

Again I apologize that this question was answered in some form in the other questions - I'm operating on a simpler level than most, so I thought this question would still be of some benefit to others.

Comment: The statement is false if you take $A$ to be empty, and $B$ to be non-empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't follow your definition of $g$. Are you picking some element $a \in A$, then defining a constant function from $B$ to $A$, mapping every element of $B$ to this one element $a$? If so, this is (in general) not a surjection!

Here's the way I'd do it. Let $C$ be the range of $f$. Note that, if we restrict the codomain of $f$ to $C$, then $f$ is a surjection too, and hence invertible. Let $h : C \to A$ be this inverse. Note that $h$ is invertible too, and hence is surjective.

All we need to do is extend $h$ to map from all of $B$ to $A$. Note that since $h$ is surjective, all elements of $A$ are currently being mapped to, so the other points in $B$ can map to literally anywhere we want in $A$.

Choose some fixed $a_0 \in A$, and define $g : B \to A$ as follows:
$$g(b) = \begin{cases} h(b) & \text{if } b \in C \\ a_0 & \text{if } b \notin C \end{cases}.$$
Then, if $a \in A$, then since $h$ is a surjection (since it is invertible), there exists some $b \in C$ such that $h(b) = a$. By definition, $g(b) = a$ too, hence $g$ is a surjection.

Comment: My impression: the fault in my proof was in defining g(b) = a, because we have no guarantee of this existing. Your proof provides a rigorous justification that such a function g will exist - whereas I took this fact for granted?
Also, are we guaranteed to find a set C within B where f is bijective?

Comment: @kasa It's not *quite* how I'd put it. We needed to show that a $g$ with certain properties existed. In my argument, I constructed such a $g$, about as explicitly as possible. In your argument, it's unclear what the function $g$ actually is, or the properties it satisfies. If the element $a \in A$ doesn't depend on $B$, then you're defining a constant function (bad). If the element $a \in A$ does depend on $B$, then this poses no restriction on the function $g$ whatsoever (and therefore may not be surjective)! If you just wanted to assert that $g$ is surjective, then the argument is circular.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: How do you choose a fixed $a_0\in A$? What if $A$ is empty?

Comment: @AsafKaragila  for my own context, A is given as non-empty. In general though, if A is empty, then could you treat it as a separate case and define a function which returns nothing? That may not be possible though haha I'm not sure

Comment: @kasa: No, you can't quite do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're going along the right lines! An issue occurs when you're defining $g$ though - given some $b \in B$, you say that $g(b) = a$, but which $a$ are you picking for this particular $b$? How do you know that you *can* pick such an $a$?

However, if you can pick such an $a$, then your argument about why it's a surjection would be good.

Comment: Could I use the identity function to solve this problem? I haven't been taught it but I've seen it come up in related contexts. So then g(b) = $id_{a}$ or something like that ?

Comment: The identity function is just that - a function. You can't set $g(b) = id_a$ because $g(b)$ needs to be a *value* in $A$, but $id_a$ is a function...

Comment: oh doi thank you haha

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\text{range}(f) \subset B$. Map all the elements of $B-\text{range}(f)$ to any fixed element of $A$, and the elements left in $B$ are the images of some elements of $A$. Now try to complete the proof.

Comment: How do you know that $A$ has any elements?

Comment: Well, if $A = \phi$, then we can not talk about a function $f : A \rightarrow B$!!!

Comment: That is completely false.

Comment: @AsafKaragila assuming that this is a platform for learning, if you are to claim someone's argument is  "completely false" it would be respectful to explain your opinion.

Comment: @kasa: Opinion?

Comment: So you are talking about functions defined on a null set? @AsafKaragila

Comment: In case $A = \phi$, $f$ is the empty function and $g$ does not exist in this case. So we need to assume $A \neq \phi$.